# Huge Memory Leak from Node.js setInterval + mssql

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, setinterval, infinite-loop

I have an application that run exact this code:

```
const sql = require("mssql");   
const config_TDATA02 = {
    user:       'sa',
    password:   'password',
    server:     '132.222.222.222',
    port:       22100,
    database:   'DBTEST'
};
function start(cfg) {

    setInterval(function(cfg){
        doSomething(cfg);        
    }, 300, cfg)
}
function doSomething(cfg) {
    let query = "select 1 as first"
    ExecuteQuery(cfg, query)
}
async function ExecuteQuery(cfg, query) {

    try {

        await sql.connect(cfg)
        const result = await sql.query`select 1 as first`
        console.dir(result)
        sql.close()
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('error', err)
        sql.close()
    }
}

// init program
start(config_TDATA02)
```

As you can see, it's a very simple code, but my memory explodes very fast, does anyone have any tips on why I'm having this problem?

Comment: Try to connect once and reuse the same connection: move the line `await sql.connect(cfg)` before you `setInterval` and try again.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, it got a little better, now it's taking a little longer for the memory to explode, I noticed that the garbage collector was triggered a few times as the memory suddenly decreased. Basically now it's taking longer to allocate more memory but problem continues.

Comment: Try to increase the interval then, it could be that sending queries every 300 ms is too much for your machine

Comment: I changed my code to webhooks... 300ms is really too much. I followed this: https://blog.cloud-elements.com/webhooks-vs-polling-youre-better-than-this